# TinyMCE JS returns 404 in django project

Tags: django, tinymce

I am getting a 404 in my local server when trying to load TinyMCE JS files. I am using the `django-mce` package, I have downloaded the latest mce files and added them to my `media` directory. In attempting to use them with a form, a 404 is returned.

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms
from tinymce.widgets import TinyMCE

class post(forms.Form):
  description = forms.CharField(widget=TinyMCE(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 30}))
```

*settings.py*

```
# File Management

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# tinymce

TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "js/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js")
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, "js/tiny_mce")

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme': 'advanced',
    'relative_urls': False,
    'plugins': 'media',
    'theme_advanced_buttons1': 'bold,italic,underline,bullist,numlist,|,media,link,unlink,image',
}
```

The tiny mce js files are stored in `proj/media/js/tiny_mce` with the base js file saved as `tinymce.min.js`

*base.html*

```
<head>
...
{{ form.media }}
...
</head>
```

The editor is working (as far as columns and rows go) but is missing the toolbar. Also the local server returns `GET proj/media/js/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 3024` and at this point I'm at a loss. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you prefixing it with `proj/`? Your `MEDIA_URL` setting does not contain anything like that.

Comment: @IvanStarostin `BASE_DIR` is the absolute `Users/name/Desktop/proj` so my media root should be `Users/name/Desktop/proj/media`

Comment: `GET proj/media/js/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js` -> `GET media/js/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js` I'm talking about MEDIA_URL.

Comment: @IvanStarostin, this didn't work but it did get me on the correct path, it wanted to load from static when I stopped using `os.path.join` for the media path, so I just created the static files for tinymce and then used them as my tinymce url and root and it worked perfectly. If you want to throw that up as an answer I'll accept it, thanks!